# Blender + iPad (sidecar) - how can i quickly use undo

Tags: shortcut

I can use Blender on iPad via Sidecar - no problem with that.

Just the "handling" isn't that clear to me.

e.g. For "undo" - do i really have to tap 2 times on the command button on the left side, then open keyboard and tap on z? This sounds a bit too complicated for me. Does anybody know a quicker way to undo in Blender on iPad/sidecar?